# Xamarin.UITest 3.0.14 apksigner not found

Tags: android, windows, xamarin.uitest

After upgrading to Xamarin.UITest v.3.0.14 from 3.0.13, APK loading breaks when attempting to sign.

```
Android SDK not found. Please install it and if it is still not located, please set the ANDROID_HOME environment variable to point to the directory.

Searched locations: 
Windows Registry
C:\Users\xxxx\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk - Partial match. Found: zipalign, aapt, adb, android.jar Missing: apksigner [ Source: ANDROID_HOME ]
```

A quick search for "apksigner" at %ANDROID_HOME% shows it's located under build-tools/30.0.3/lib as .jar file, and build-tools/30.0.3 as .bat file, as well as under build-tools/29.0.2.

Is there a  workaround to get Xamarin.UITest to find apksigner?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yeah I noticed the same error : Xamarin.UITest 3.0.14 doesn't accept the apksigner.bat file. I tried to create a file named "apksigner" (without any extension, just like Linux and MacOS files for Android SDK) and the error disappeared. But this workaround will raise another error and the problem will remain.

The only solution I found is to downgrade your Xamarin.UITest to 3.0.13, because (in my opinion) 3.0.14 will only work with Linux and MacOS.

The next version should solve this problem, so we just have to wait ^^